# Ifthenelse conditionals in moderncv's cventry

Tags: conditionals, moderncv

Now that Frodo has left to fight Sauron, Bilbo is all alone at home and searching for new things to do. So it came to his mind that he could apply for a job. For his application, he uses the `moderncv` documentclass and therein the `\cventry` command for the educational stages of his life with a typical entry being `\cventry[spacing]{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}{localization}{optionnal: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}`.

Since he's applying for several jobs and is a person working effectively, he is reusing some parts of his CV for the different applications. However, he wants to have some pieces of information in the CV to show up only for certain conditions. Since he plans to apply for jobs in The Shire as well as in other parts of Middle Earth, one of the conditions is that for jobs outside of The Shire, he wants to have "The Shire" added to names of places. He does not want to add that for applications within The Shire, since he expects that people are familiar with the localities.

Unfortunately, concerning the "institution" and "localization" field in the `\cventy` there are two different cases which can be seen in the MWE below: In some cases the institution's name does already contain the location name, e.g. "Bag's End Hobbit School", while others don't contain such a localized name. In the former case, the "localization" field should *only* contain the country and *only*, if the applications is for an employer outside The Shire. In the latter case, the "localization" should contain the city name for applications within The Shire and "City, The Shire" for applications in the rest of Middle Earth.

To achieve this, Bilbo has defined a boolean variable `international` which should be tested to decide which localization should be used. This does work fine in other entry types (see the `\cvitem` entry by the end of the MWE), but not in the `\cventry` command, where putting an `\ifthenelse` statement into one of the arguments results in "! Argument of \boolean has an extra }." errors.

To me, the crux seems to be in the way the `\cventry` command is parsed (the respective original code is in the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` section). However, I have no idea what to change to get it working or how to work around it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\makeatother

\newboolean{international}
\setboolean{international}{true}

% personal data
\name{Bilbo}{Baggins}
\address{A house in}{Bag's End}{The Shire}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{2130--2135}{Hobbit}{Bag's End Hobbit School}{The Shire}{}{}
\cventry{2130--2135}{Hobbit}{Bag's End Hobbit School}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{international}}{}{The Shire}}{}{}
\cventry{2126--2130}{Small Hobbit}{"The smallest Ones" Primary School}{Bag's End\ifthenelse{\boolean{international}}{}{, The Shire}}{}{}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{There and back again}}
\cvitem{supervisor}{Gandalf the Grey}
\cvitem{description}{How I fought the Dragon\ifthenelse{\boolean{international}}{}{ and found a ring}.}
%Not everyone has to know that I have this ring...
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know `Bilbo` wasn't left at home ;-)

Comment: If you're open to `etoolbox` and its `\ifblank{}` command -- give it a try

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Damn, you're right about Bilbo... How could I forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't redefine the `\cventry` but do the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{international}
%\setbool{international}{true}
\setbool{international}{false}

\newcommand*{\mytoggle}[2]{\ifbool{international}{#1}{#2}}

% personal data
\name{Bilbo}{Baggins}
\address{A house in}{Bag's End}{The Shire}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{2130--2135}{Hobbit}{Bag's End Hobbit School}{The Shire}{}{}
\cventry{2130--2135}{Hobbit}{Bag's End Hobbit School}{\mytoggle{}{The Shire}}{}{}
\cventry{2126--2130}{Small Hobbit}{"The smallest Ones" Primary School}{Bag's End\mytoggle{}{, The Shire}}{}{}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{There and back again}}
\cvitem{supervisor}{Gandalf the Grey}
\cvitem{description}{How I fought the Dragon\mytoggle{}{ and found a ring}.}
%Not everyone has to know that I have this ring...
\end{document}
```

Comment: We had similar ideas ;-) (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Basically I don't like `\ifthenelse`. :) And nesting a conditional inside another and then another... sigh. BTW, scores leveled :)

Comment: Would `\newtoggle` do as well? That's what I had in my mind, but I've not tried yet

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Certainly. Then `\newcommand*{\mytoggle}` wouldn't be necessary :)

Comment: Go ahead ...;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: But I like `\mytoggle` since it won't need one to type `international` every time. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think `etoolbox` boolean features are safer somewhat -- this is mixed approach. I'll update after feedback

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{international}
\setbool{international}{false}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifblank{#4}{Nope}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifblank{#5}{}{, #5}%
    \ifblank{#6}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}%
\makeatother

%\newboolean{international}
%\setboolean{international}{true}

% personal data
\name{Bilbo}{Baggins}
\address{A house in}{Bag's End}{The Shire}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{2130--2135}{Hobbit}{Bag's End Hobbit School}{The Shire}{}{}
\cventry{2130--2135}{Hobbit}{Bag's End Hobbit School}{{\ifbool{international}{}{The Shire}}}{}{}
\cventry{2126--2130}{Small Hobbit}{"The smallest Ones" Primary School}{Bag's End\ifbool{international}{}{, The Shire}}{}{}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{There and back again}}
\cvitem{supervisor}{Gandalf the Grey}
\cvitem{description}{How I fought the Dragon\ifbool{international}{}{ and found a ring}.}
%Not everyone has to know that I have this ring...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The errors are gone. However, the second cventry now produces a comma and a white space, so the fifth argument isn't completely suppressed.

Comment: @BenediktBauer: I updated. I noticed and changed the boolean variable (as I already indicated in my answer leadin to the `bool` type from `etoolbox`. It's more robust, in my point of view.

Comment: Unfortunately also your updated version still produces ", " instead of being left out completely if I set international to `true`. Harish Kumar's version is working as expected.

Comment: @BenediktBauer: Yes, that `,` was already in your original `\ifthenelse{...}` code. Harish did not redefine `\cventry` and so there're no leftover's of unwanted code ;-)

Comment: Well, then it's my bad. Sorry for that!

Comment: @BenediktBauer: The wrath of Sauron will come over you :-P